# Codeigniter a view wont load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this in my controller:

```
class UpdateStats extends CI_Controller{
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();

   }
   function index(){
     $this->load->view('update_stats/index');
    }
}
```

my view (index )is in update_stats folder in view folder

When I click on the link that I created:

```
 <li id='proxy'><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/update_stats/">Master Update</a></li>
```

or in another form this:

```
  <li id='proxy'><a href="http://localhost/scanner/index.php/update_stats/">Master Update</a></li>
```

This is the error that i get:

> 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

**UPDATE** 
my filename is : updatestats.. my class name UpdateStats I try to enter to `http://localhost/scanner/index.php/updatestats`  ..and i get 404 error

FILE NAME: `updatestats.php`

CLASS NAME: `Updatestats.php`

URL DESTINATION: `http://localhost/scanner/index.php/updatestats/`

CLASS:

```
    class Updatestats extends CI_Controller{
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();

   }
   function index(){
       $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('update_stats/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: What is your base_url? Do you have a default controller set?

Comment: cant you see by my question... ?should i copy and paste it for you..: "http://localhost/scanner/"

Answer (score 1):

Your controller name is `UpdateStats` in your class declaration

```
class UpdateStats extends CI_Controller{
```

and you are using as `/update_stats/`

So make both similar, and it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is wrong. It should be

```
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/updatestats
```

Also its not the view not loading problem, it cannot even find the controller

Comment: Can you add break points in between the 3 `load->view` lines, so you can check where it is failing. You can figure out if its failing from inside the controller OR its not even reaching the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller name is `UpdateStats` but in your url you're calling `update_stats`. Change `update_stats` to `UpdateStats` and see what happens.

Comment: So rename either the controller to Update_stats OR your filename to updatestats.php (mind I'm using all lowercase here)!

Comment: Did you change the mod_rewrite to rewrite your routings?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but might be some configuration problem so i suggest you to use site_url instead of base_url as site_url creates the url according to your site configuration in your case it would be:

```
<li id='proxy'><a href="<?php echo site_url('updatestats');?>">Master Update</a></li>
```